# Why are these registers pushed to stack?

Tags: assembly

```
push    %ebp
push    %esp, %ebp
push    edi
push    esi
push    ebx
```

(x86 32bit Linux)

Why are these registers pushed to stack?
Migrated for some reason...?
But, why only 'edi' 'esi' 'ebx' are pushed?

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), in particular [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a gcc implementation detail for the x86 code generator.  Surprisingly hard to find good docs for it, I did find [this page](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2004/lec/l2.html) which is pretty accurate.  Key part:

> after ret instruction:
>
> ```
> %eip contains return address
> %esp points at arguments pushed by caller
> called function may have trashed arguments
> %eax contains return value (or trash if function is void)
> %ecx, %edx may be trashed
> %ebp, %ebx, %esi, %edi must contain contents from time of call
> ```

The "must contain content from time of call" phrase explains why their are pushed in the function prologue and popped again in the epilogue.

Comment: plus "%eax, %ecx, %edx are "caller save" registers"